# How do I link my BigCartel Shop to my Pinterest Business account?

Tags: html, css, e-commerce, pinterest, bigcartel

I copied code to insert on my BigCartel shop so I can get my products to upload to my Pinterest account. I'm looking for the "Head" section in my code and can't find it. I'm not much of a coder, but I think I can copy and paste if I knew where to put it :-).

Please advise.

Thanks,
Sharon
[www.rollershirts.com](http://www.rollershirts.com)

Comment: Assuming the same reference, the `<head>` is a tag in the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Evening Sharon,

The "head" of your code that you're referring to would most likely be the `<head>` tag in the html.

A very basic website would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the `<head>` tag is right after the first `<html>` tag.

If your website does not have this tag, simply add it to the proper area. (Within the `<html>` tag but before the `<body>` tag.)

Paste the code you said you got like the example I give below:

```
<head YourCodeStringHere>
```